# How to detect the variable when used?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

how to call a function every call of a variable? is the code below is possible?
i'm planning to call a function every time "num" is used..

```
if (num == 100 && num== 200 && num==300) {
  console.log('it works!');
}
```

Comment: can you *please* show one example of how you will use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valueOf` abuse is one option, but there are many others.

```js
const num = {
  value: 0,
  valueOf: function() {
    this.value += 100;
    return this.value;
  }
}
if (num == 100 && num== 200 && num==300) {
  console.log('it works!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript [proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to define custom behavior for fundamental operations including the assignment.

You can override methods for arrays, objects etc using it.

Please find an example given in MDM. This one has a trap for setting property values. We can have traps for set, has and other operarions like for constructors etc.

```
let validator = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop === 'age') {
      if (!Number.isInteger(value)) {
        throw new TypeError('The age is not an integer');
      }
      if (value > 200) {
        throw new RangeError('The age seems invalid');
      }
    }

    // The default behavior to store the value
    obj[prop] = value;

    // Indicate success
    return true;
  }
};

let person = new Proxy({}, validator);

person.age = 100;
console.log(person.age); // 100
person.age = 'young'; // Throws an exception
person.age = 300; // Throws an exception
```

---

Answer (score 1):

`toString` also works:

```js
const num = {
  value: 0,
  toString: function() {
    this.value += 100;
    return this.value;
  }
}
if (num == 100 && num== 200 && num==300) {
  console.log('it works!');
}
```

however,`valueOf` preferred

```js
const num = {
  value: 0,
  toString: function() {
    this.value += 1000;
    return this.value;
  },
  valueOf: function() {
    this.value += 100;
    return this.value;
  }
}
if (num == 100 && num == 200 && num == 300) {
  console.log('it works with valueOf');
}

if (num == 1000 && num == 2000 && num == 3000) {
  console.log('it works with toString');
}
```

Comment: why its not working in console.log()? i thought every call of num the value is changing ..by the way thank you. :)

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz what ?which one?

Comment: both. i try to console.log(num) 3x times, i thought it will return 100,200,300. is this working only in if statement?

Comment: @PauloDelaCruz,is this what you want?let n = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, "num", {
  get() {
    return (n += 100);
  }
});
console.log(num);
console.log(num);
console.log(num);